# Using separable verbs with prepositions

Tags: separable-verb

Which is correct?

- Ist es in Ordnung, wenn ich nehme am Meeting nicht teil?
- Ist es in Ordnung, wenn ich nicht am Meeting teilnehme?

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/separating-separable-verbs?rq=1) and (to some extent) [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/separable-verbs-using-zu-in-the-infinitive?rq=1). Also (https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/66006/how-bad-does-it-sound-in-german-not-to-separate-separable-verbs?rq=1 [here]).

Comment: @bakunin: I agree. To clarify a bit, *wenn* is a conjunction (not a preposition) which creates a subordinate clause, and all parts of the verb are placed at the end in a subordinate clause. The prepositions here are *in* and *an* (part of *an dem* = *am*).

Comment: This has nothing to with prepositions. As RDBury correctly noted, there is a subordinate clause which demands verb-last order, and separable verbs are not split if they are last in a clause.